# Propagating property changes in C# across multiple classes

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

I'm using C#, WPF, and .NETcore3.1 to design a GUI. This is the first time I've used C#, so the project structure I have might seem unusual or suboptimal. While suggestions to make the code more C# friendly are welcome (in that I expect a number of 'use MVVM' answers), that isn't the main question I have here.

I've ended up with the following general structure :

1. A DLL project which does the business logic, mostly independent of the GUI
2. A WPF application which I want to use to display information from the DLL

Class-wise, this looks like

1. A class in the DLL (for the purpose of this question, in practice is a set of classes) which holds the actual business logic, and for all practical purposes you can assume will get changed asynchronously. Lets call this BusinessLogicClass
2. A class in the GUI project which creates a presentation layer of sorts, essentially reshaping the relevant properties of the BusinessLogicClass into formats that can be directly consumed from the XAML using Bindings. Let's call this the PresentationLayerClass. Note that this is implemented as a User Control.
3. The XAML GUI itself. Specifically, the XAML GUI for the custom control.

Some pseudocode :

```
// In the DLL

class BusinessLogicClass:
    public Boolean status{ get; set; }

// In the GUI

Using DLLNamespace;

public partial class PresentationLayerClass : UserControl

    private BusinessLogicClass actual;

    public PresentationLayerClass(BusinessLogicClass actual){
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        this.actual = actual; 
    }

    public string ConnectionStatus{
        get{
            if (this.actual.status == true) return "LanConnect";
            else return "LanDisconnect";
        }        
    }

    public string StatusColor{ 
        get {
            if (this.actual.status == true) return "Green";
            else return "Red";
        }
    }

// In the XAML
<iconPacks:PackIconMaterial Kind="{Binding ConnectionStatus}" Margin="5" Foreground="{Binding StatusColor}"/>
```

Now, I understand (though have not yet worked out how to test this) that when the properties of the PresentationLayerClass are changed, the GUI will 'update itself'.

What I would like is that async changes to the status property of the BusinessLogicClass get propagated up the chain all the way to the GUI.

If necessary, for the sake of simplicity and because I don't know enough yet to explain more, assume that everything's on the same thread and the changes which are async are being triggered by the user on the GUI itself. Say a button. However, the button and this display do not and must not know anything about each other. The information must necessarily pass through the DLL, and the DLL must trigger the change to the update.

Also, the DLL should not be hardcoded to the GUI - I want to be able to run the DLL by itself or with a CLI application or another GUI.

I am hoping some combination of INotifyPropertyChanged would do the job, but I can't seem to figure out how I would set that up. INotifyPropertyChanged seems to always be discussed in the context of GUIs and Bindings.

I understand that MVVM is supposed to help simplify this sort of thing. While I have reasons to want to avoid MVVM in this particular instance, I will admit I'm not yet entirely convinced that MVVM is worth the trouble in general. I'm quite averse to the apparently implicit links popular MVVM libraries establish. I have no intention of starting a philosophical discussion on MVVM, but anyone who wishes to disabuse me of that notion may make their case as an aside - as long as you understand that MVVM isn't the subject of the question I ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not to tell you what you already know, but a lot of your questions might be answered by just reading up on the [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged) interface.

---

## `INotifyPropertyChanged` Summary

Normally, no object knows if another object's properties have changed unless a check is performed. This is essentially the purpose of events, to raise an alarm when something changes so other objects don't have to keep checking all the time. But there are numerous way to declare events with all kinds of different signatures.

`INotifyPropertyChanged` provides a simple, basic standard that can be used to tell other objects when something changes, and what property was changed. It defines the `PropertyChanged` event, which includes as an argument the name of the property that was changed. A type that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` is responsible for explicitly raising the `PropertyChanged` event when a property changes, this is usually done in the `set` method of each property.

The WPF framework is designed to support the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. WPF data bindings check for objects that implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and listen for the `PropertyChanged` event. When that even is raised, they check `PropertyChangedEventArgs.PropertyName` to see which property was changed. If that property is bound to, WPF knows to update that binding.

In WPF, there are also [dependency properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-properties-overview). These have a lot useful features, but the most pertinent is that they also implement their own change notification, which WPF knows to look out for.

---

## Your Implementation

The way you have `PresentationLayerClass` defined currently, the UI *will not* automatically update if either `ConnectionStatus` or `StatusColor` change. This is because those properties are not implemented as either dependency properties or `INotifyPropertyChanged` properties. Of course, both of those take their values from `BusinessLogicClass`, so let's start there.

`BusinessLogicClass` should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and the `status` property should raise the `PropertyChanged` event when it is set.

Along with that, you need to add an event handler to `PresentationLayerClass` for that event. Example:
`private void BusinessLogic_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)` and attach the handler in the constructor (`public PresentationLayerClass` method).

Now at the `PresentationLayerClass` level, in the `BusinessLogic_PropertyChanged` method, you have to check which property of `BusinessLogicClass` has been changed (by using `PropertyChangedEventArgs.PropertyName`), and then update the values for any property of `PresentationLayerClass` which is dependent on that changed property. Updating the dependent properties will be different depending on which pattern you decide to use:

- **`PresentationLayerClass` uses dependency properties**: You will have to explicitly set the new values for each dependent dependency property.
- **`PresentationLayerClass` uses `INotifyPropertyChanged`**: You will have to raise the `PropertyChanged` event once for every dependent property. (Pro tip: use [`nameof`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof) instead of hard-coding the property name).